Setting up DMARC and DKIM for subdomains not hosted on the same server as the main domain
The Setup
I have the following setup.
example.com is hosted on one server (let's call it Server A), with the IPv4 of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
Two subdomains are hosted on another server (we'll call it Server B):

info.example.com, IPv4 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
marketing.example.com, IPv4 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

I want to setup DMARC and DKIM for both subdomains (info and marketing), and I want to use the private DKIM for AWS identity creation (option BYODKIM). To do this, I've setup the DNS records like so:
Server A (cPanel, Zone editor)
A record
 - example.com, TTL 600, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 - mail.example.com, TTL 600, xxx.xxx.xxx
 - info.example.com, TTL 600, yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
 - mail.info.example.com, TTL 600, yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
 - marketing.example.com, TTL 600, yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
 - mail.marketing.example.com, TTL 600, yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

MX record
 - example.com, TTL 600, Priority 0, Destination: mail.example.com
 - info.example.com, TTL 600, Priority: 0, Destination: mail.info.example.com
 - marketing.example.com, TTL 600, Priority: 0, Destination: mail.marketing.example.com

Server B (internal settings, user account level, non-cPanel)
A record
 - info.example.com, TTL 600, yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
 - mail.info.example.com, TTL 600, yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
 - marketing.example.com, TTL 600, yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
 - mail.marketing.example.com, TTL 600, yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

MX record
 - info.example.com, TTL 600, Priority: 0, Destination: mail.info.example.com
 - marketing.example.com, TTL 600, Priority: 0, Destination: mail.marketing.example.com

TXT record
 - info.example.com, TTL 600, v=spf1 ip4:yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy +a +mx ~all
 - marketing.example.com, TTL 600, v=spf1 ip4:yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy +a +mx ~all
 - _dmarc.info.example.com, TTL 600, v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:no-reply@info.example.com; ruf=mailto:no-reply@info.example.com; fo=0
 - _dmarc.marketing.example.com, TTL 600, v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:no-reply@marketing.example.com; ruf=mailto:no-reply@marketing.example.com; fo=0
 - dkim._domainkey.info.example.com, TTL 600, v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=<public_dkim>
 - dkim._domainkey.marketing.example.com, TTL 600, v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=<public_dkim>


The problem
When using external tools, like Dmarcian, or MXToolbox, or Mail tester, or WhatsMyDNS, I am unable to verify my setup - for example, DMARC and DKIM are nowhere to be found, and a general TXT lookup also comes back empty.
What I did notice is that Server A (where the main domain is) is being queried in all cases, instead of Server B (where the subdomains are).
What is wrong with my setup? The propagation is not the issue, as it has been more than a week since this has been setup (two, in fact, because other priorites came up).
Should I be setting up DMARC and DKIM for my subdomains on Server A (where the main domain is)? Doing this somehow feels wrong, since the subdomains are hosted on Server B.

The subdomains may be hosted on server B, but DNS records are stored on the server where the nameservers are pointing.
So you should be setting them up on Server A.

That did the trick - I just copied my DKIM and DMARC entries from Server B to Server A, and used DKIM private key from Server B on Amazon. Everything worked. Thanks.
